# S3 Bucket name information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have an S3 bucket name for example: demo-adminstage.
Is there a way I can figure out what the full domain of the bucket is?
and not demo-adminstage.s3.amazonaws.com (for example is demo-adminstage.com)
What information can I get about a bucket just by knowing its name?

Comment: No.  S3 has no such information, it's in other services such as Route53, CloudFront, or even outside of AWS, depending on how the DNS records are configured and what service is actually serving up the website.

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ do you want to know the "full domain of the bucket"? I ask because it depends on how you are wanting to access/use the bucket. What is your particular use-case?